# Symfony 2.1 form unit testing on bind event

Tags: symfony, phpunit, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

I am trying to test a method on the bind event of a custom form type.

Here is the code

```
public function bind(DataEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm();

    if($form->getNormData() instanceof BaseFileInterface && !$event->getData() instanceof UploadedFile) {
        $event->setData($form->getNormData());
    }

    if($event->getData() instanceof UploadedFile) {
        $hander = $this->handlerManager->getHandler(
            $form->getParent()->getConfig()->getDataClass(), 
            $form->getName()
        );

        $datas = $hander->createBaseFile($event->getData());
        $event->setData($datas);
    }

    if(is_string($event->getData())) {
        $event->setData(null);
    }
}
```

and the form builder of the type :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->addEventSubscriber(new BaseFileListener($this->handlerManager))
        ->addViewTransformer(new BaseFileToStringTransformer())
    ;
}
```

My test class inherits from Symfony\Component\Form\Tests\FormIntegrationTestCase and is doing this :

```
protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->handlerManager = $this->getHandlerManagerMock();

    $this->dispatcher = $this->getMock('Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface');
    $this->builder = new FormBuilder(null, null, $this->dispatcher, $this->factory);

    $this->form =  $this->factory->create('my_file');
    $this->form->setParent($this->getFormMock())->setData(new DummyEntity());
}

protected function getFormMock()
{

    $mock = $this
        ->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\Form\Tests\FormInterface')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock()
    ;

    return $mock;
}

public function testBindHandleNewFileWithNonEmptyField()
{
    $data = $file = new UploadedFile(
        __DIR__.'/../Fixtures/test.gif',
        'original.gif',
        'image/gif',
        filesize(__DIR__.'/../Fixtures/test.gif'),
        null
    );

    $event = new FormEvent($this->form, $data);

    $listener = new BaseFileListener($this->handlerManager);
    $listener->bind($event);

    $this->assertInstanceOf('My\FooBundle\Entity\BaseFileInterface', $event->getData());
    $this->assertNotEquals($event->getData(), $this->form->getNormData());
}
```

The probleme is that the $form->getParent()->getConfig()->getDataClass() throws an exception on getDataClass ().

The question is how to build the form correctly to perform the bind test ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, answering my self :)

Here is the good mocking in phpunit :

```
protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->handlerManager = $this->getHandlerManagerMock();

    $this->dispatcher = $this->getMock('Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface');
    $this->builder = new FormBuilder(null, null, $this->dispatcher, $this->factory);

    $this->form =  $this->factory->create('my_file');
    $this->form->setParent($this->getFormMock());
}

protected function getFormMock()
{
    $mock = $this->getMock('Symfony\Component\Form\Tests\FormInterface');

    $mock
        ->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getConfig')
        ->will($this->returnValue($this->getFormConfigMock()))
    ;

    return $mock;
}

protected function getFormConfigMock()
{
    $mock = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\Form\FormConfigInterface')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $mock
        ->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getDataClass')
        ->will($this->returnValue('My\FooBundle\Tests\DummyEntity'))
    ;

    return $mock;
}
```

I thought I could manage to rebuild the entire form without using mock, but it seems impossible.

If someone has a better solution to offer I'm interested.